# Correct way to parse (option)arguments, questions about getopt(3) and argv

Tags: c

As an example I want to implement the following function:
listtool [-s | -a NUM] < string >

My approach was the following:

```
int opt;
int opt_s = -1, opt_a = -1, num;
char *optstr ="<not yet set>";
num = -1;

if( argc < 3 || argc > 4 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Wrong number of arguments");
    usage();
}

/* Options */
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "sa:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
    case 's': {
        if (opt_s != -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "opt_s multiple times\n");
            usage();         /* does not return */
        }
        else if (opt_a != -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Please only choose one option\n");
            usage();
        }
        else {
            ++opt_s;
            break;
        }
    }
    case 'a': {
        if (opt_a != -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "opt_a multiple times\n");
            usage();        /* does not return */
        }
        else if (opt_s != -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Please only choose one option\n");
            usage();
        }
            ++opt_a;
            ++num; 
            break;
        }
    case '?': {
        usage();
        break;
    }
    // Impossible
    default: {
        assert(0);
    }
    }
}

/* Arguments */
if( num > -1 ) {
    if( (argc - optind) != 2 ) {
        usage();
    }
    num = (int)strtol( argv[optind], NULL, 0 );
    *optstr = argv[optind+1];
}
else {
    if( (argc - optind) != 1 ) {
        usage();
    }
    *optstr = argv[optind];
}
```

There are a few things about this code which don't work. I want to know why, and what is the right way to do this.

- First of all getopt is trying to parse the arguments and than goes into the ? case
- (optind - argc) doesn't throw the right number of arguments
- the assignment of argv[optind] to optstr throws:

  `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast`

Thank you in advance for every answer

Comment: Have you looked at: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html ?  Also, a google search for 'advanced linux programing pdf' will pick up a pdf that has a good argument program example.

Comment: Yeah of course I looked it up on serval resources, thats why I am asking.

Comment: for example the part with the (argc - optind) I got straight from a example thats why I am wondering it wont work

Comment: You dereference optstr, that's the int that it is talking about.  As far as the rest of the code, it's so far away from standard that it is a mess to try to understand.  Get the examples working and move from there.

Comment: How, exactly, are you running your program ?

Comment: gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_BSD_SOURCE -o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to 3rd question `the assignment of argv[optind] to optstr throws: warning ?` is as follows,

```
char *optstr; 
*optstr = argv[optind]; // Wrong if LHS is a string rather a char
```

```
optstr = argv[optind]; // Correct one
```

Here, `optstr` is a pointer to character which can store a single char or a string. 
Also `*optstr` refers to `char` and RHS `argv[optind]` is a string refers to a pointer. Hence the warning.